# VS 2022 - Convert to file-scoped namespace in all files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I'm converting my project to .NET 6 and I want to use filescoped namespaces everywhere. But the conversion tool exists only in the editor.

[image: file-scoped namespace conversion]

Has anyone found out if there's a way to run this editor function across all files in solution at once? (Looks like Rider has that function)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Adding a rule to use file scoped namespaces in `.editorconfig` worked for me:

- create an `.editorconfig` file in the solution directory
- add following line/content below ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#namespace-options), [code - IDE0161](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/6884d36627795f1e00303bf4a068dd7998667bd9/src/Analyzers/Core/Analyzers/IDEDiagnosticIds.cs#L164))

Example `.editorconfig` file content:

```
[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:warning
```

After that the preview changes dialog had an option to apply the fix to the whole project/solution:

[image]

Comment: Need to add prev line to [*.cs] else not working. Usage:
[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped

Answer (score 61):

I always have problems finding files that are supposed to be updated (.editorconfig in this case). I don't even know if I should search for it in the project's, Visual Studio installation's or any folder on the PC. So I like the answer in the link below because it says where in the interface to change the setting.

Best answer in my opinion is here:
https://www.ilkayilknur.com/how-to-convert-block-scoped-namespacees-to-file-scoped-namespaces

It says that you can change the code-style preference (and enable the display of the option to apply this preference in a document / project / solution) by going to Tools => Options => Text Editor => C#=> Code Style and then changing the related preference.
[image]

Comment: You don't want to do that, because that is IDE level. You can generate literally thousands of merge changes/conflict by this change.

Comment: That's why as a team you agree when to make such a change and you do it in isolation and get everyone on the same page before continuing more work..?

Comment: well, this doesnt generate existing changed, it only applies to new code and suggestions if you chose to do so, at the same time it applies to each new project which is what you'd likely want. Anyway, should be a team decision as mentioned

Answer (score 12):

### EditorConfig syntax

```
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = error
```

#### Note

Syntax `option = rule:severity` will be [deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44201), sooner or later.

I strongly recommend to read [this article](https://developers.mews.com/c-code-style-by-editorconfig-in-net-5-sdk-and-beyond/) before you start build `.editorconfig` for your project.

Comment: Or maybe it won't be deprecated after all: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52991

Comment: and run 'dotnet format'

Answer (score 6):

After you have configured the `.editorconfig`, you can configure a 'Code Cleanup' setting to automatically convert all files to use file-scoped namespace. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Cleanup -> Configure Code Cleanup. Then add the 'Apply namespace preferences'. Then go to Analyze -> Code Cleanup (or just search for 'Code cleanup') and run the Code Cleanup to automatically change the namespaces to file-scoped.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but my experience is that neither this nor the accepted answer actually change all the files in a solution. I change the Code Cleanup option and then right click on the solution and it only changes some of them. If I click it again. . .it changes more of them, which makes no sense. The accepted answer has similar problems