# Why can't I save some editor config settings to the local file?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

Looking at this question: [How can I use a file-scoped namespace declaration in a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998050/how-can-i-use-a-file-scoped-namespace-declaration-in-a-class-template)

The answer shows an example:[image]

But when I add a file "Editor Config(.Net)" to my project it doesn't look the same:

1. many settings are hard-coded to Location = Visual Studio Settings
2. the severity options do not match that screenshot at all

[image]

I am also using VS2022 like the other question (Pro version in my case). What is going on? There's no point me adding a .editorconfig file to Git under my project if the settings I want to change aren't stored in that file.