# Why does Visual Studio 2022 not honor my C# template file when creating a new class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Namespace alteration]

I edited the Class.cs file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class. The changes are applied when I create a new class file, but Visual Studio seems to override the single line namespace declaration with the older syntax. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried to change the style options related to namespace declarations in the `Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> General` section, so your preference is reflected in the new class file? You don't need to modify the class template

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the default value of the Namespace declaration in Code Style is Block scoped. You need to change it to File scoped.

Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> General -> Namespace declaration -> File scoped

[image]

For another method, please refer to: [How can I use a file-scoped namespace declaration in a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998050/how-can-i-use-a-file-scoped-namespace-declaration-in-a-class-template)