# How to generate class with file-scoped namespace syntax (C# 10) in vs code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I would like to generate a new `C#` Class or `C#` Interface in Microsoft Visual Studio Code following the newest `C#10` file-scoped namespace syntax.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces

> Beginning with C# 10, you can declare a namespace for all types
> defined in that file, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> namespace SampleNamespace;
>
> class AnotherSampleClass
> {
>     public void AnotherSampleMethod()
>     {
>         System.Console.WriteLine(
>             "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace");
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm generating C# classes this way:

Right click on folder in the explorer -> New C# Class.

The output looks like this: (the old syntax with curly braces)

> ```
> namespace SampleNamespace
> {
>     class SampleClass
>     {
>         public void SampleMethod()
>         {
>             System.Console.WriteLine(
>                 "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm using `C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).` `v1.24.0`

VS Code version is `1.62.3`

Is there any way to override the generator behaviour to generate new file-scoped namespace syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS 2022 - Convert to file-scoped namespace in all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889519/vs-2022-convert-to-file-scoped-namespace-in-all-files)

Comment: Just delete the curly bracket after the namespace, and at the file end, put a semicolon after the namespace and un-dent the whole file (Ctrl-a, shift-tab)?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm lazy :), I don't want to repeat these steps every time I created a new class.

Comment: "It's not lazy, it's efficient"

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MrDave1999 No :/

Comment: There is an extension called [csharpextensions](https://github.com/jchannon/csharpextensions) (no longer maintained), however, you could add a new template [here](https://github.com/jchannon/csharpextensions/tree/master/templates) with file-scoped namespace sintax.
I'm not very good at JavaScript :(, otherwise I would make a fork and publish a new extension with that feature.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sorry this is a late response but I've just been at this myself.

What you're looking for is a Visual Studio setting.

Go to: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style

The 4th block down, "Code block preferences"

Change "Namespace declarations" from "Block scoped" to "File scoped"

(This is in Visual Studio 2022)

**EDIT (Dec 22nd):**

For VS Code, I have installed "C# Extensions" by JosKreativ

Once installed, go to: File > Preferences > Settings

In the "Search settings" textbox type "namespace"

You'll see the option (for me 3rd);

"Csharpextensions: Use File Scoped Namespace"

Check that checkbox and you're good to go.

Comment: This is a great instruction for Visual studio but the question was how to implement it in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get the answer you seek in terms of changing the generator, you could consider:

- Install AutoHotKey
- Add this to the AHK script:

```
; CtrlAltN - convert to file scoped namespace
^!N::
KeyWait Control
KeyWait Alt
Send ^{Home}{Down}{Delete}{Delete}^{End}{Backspace}^a+{Tab}
return
```

- Make a new class
- Put the cursor anywhere in it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

It literally presses the following keys (after waiting for you to release Ctrl, Alt)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> - cursor to top of file
- <kbd>Down</kbd> - cursor to `{` line
- <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> - remove `{` and line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> - go to end
- <kbd>Bksp</kbd> - remove `}`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> - select all
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - undent

I'm sure you can tweak the script as required; `;` prefixing a line is a comment, `^!N::` is a hotkey `^` means Ctrl, `!` means Alt, `+` means Shift.. Then the other keys are either `{named}` or `literal` chars

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the [snippets created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50659099/1647238), you will find `namespace` and `fsnamespace` (file name namespace).

In short, you should start typing **fsnamespace** until you get the suggestion and then press enter.

Another option is to create a snippet. To do that, go to Preferences -> Configure User Snippets -> *Select if you want it for the language or project* and then paste the following:

```
"Namespace": {
    "prefix": "namespace",
    "body": [
        "namespace ${1:Name};"
    ],
    "description": "Namespace"
},
```

Answer (score -2):

you should go to user preference settings (ctrl + alt + p), search for namespace and check csharpextension: use file scoped namespace. And it will work for all .NET 6 + projects

Comment: Does it work in vs code?